# Converte número negativo para positivo

Tags: java

Existe alguma biblioteca nativa do java que me ajude de uma forma elegante de converter um número negativo para positivo.

Eu não queria fazer dessa maneira:

```
public class Main {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int i1 = 10;  
        int i2 = -i1;  
        int i3 = -i2;  

        System.out.printf("%d\n%d\n%d", i1, i2, i3);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: [Math.abs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int))

Comment: `Math.abs(number);`

Comment: Use a boa e velha matemática, basta multiplicar por -1 `int i2 = i1 * (-1)` e use um `if (i1 < 0)` para checar se o numero é negativo.

Comment: @OlimonF., basta fazer `int i2 = -i1`, não?

Comment: @PedroLorentz não sou muito experiente com java, mas acho que as 3 soluções postadas devem funcionar, mas não sei quanto a performance de cada uma ou o jeito certo. POr isso postei como comentário e não resposta :|

Comment: @OlimonF., no texto da pergunta ele já tinha usado `-i1`, hehe. Quanto a performance, é esperado que a multiplicação seja mais lenta sim (mas eu espero que o compilador consiga otimizar e transformar no operador unário).

Comment: [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041632/how-to-compute-the-integer-absolute-value) tem uma solução interessante (para C++, mas deve funcionar em Java também).

Comment: Sinceramente eu não entendi sua pergunta. Você quer um maneira de converter um negativo para um positivo mais simples do que colocar um sinal de negativo na frente da variável? Acho que é impossível. Talvez o que você quis perguntar não foi exatamente isso, se for o caso por favor esclareça a sua pergunta.

Comment: Sinceramente eu que não entendi sua pergunta. Em qual momento não ficou explícito que, eu procurava uma forma de conversão de positivo para negativo sem alterações de sinais explicitamente. Como o @bfavaretto falou, Math.abs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O grande truque é usar a função matemática módulo ou [valor absoluto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valor_absoluto_%28%C3%A1lgebra%29) para imprimir o que se deseja. Por ser uma função bastante comum é possível encontrá-la na maioria das linguagens de programação em java a mesma está definida em [Math.abs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) e abs() é a sigla para absoluto em inglês.

Desta forma o seu código poderia usar desta forma:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i1 = -10;
        //Pega o valor absoluto de i1 isto é o módulo do mesmo
        int i2 = Math.abs(i1);
        System.out.println(i1);
        System.out.println(i2);
    }
}
```

Outra forma de fazer isso seria através de expressões regulares, **mas não faria sentido usar uma expressão regular** e conversões só para pegar o módulo de um número uma vez que esta operação ficaria muito custosa (embora possível):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i1 = -10;
        String regex = "" + i1;
        regex = regex.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(regex);
        System.out.println(i2);
    }
}
```

Note que é praticamente a mesma coisa se fizesse com o replace:

```
regex = regex.replaceAll("-", "");
```

ou ainda

```
regex = regex.substring(1); //retira o primeiro caractere
```

Embora todos estes métodos funciona **não compensa criar um objeto String somente para fazer uma conversão** quando Java já fornece a função na Biblioteca Math.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a sugestão de @Olimon F. e resolvendo em apenas uma linha

```
int i2 = -1;
int x = ((i2 < 0) ? -i2 : i2);
System.out.println(x);

// output: 1
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que a `Math.abs` faz, mas acho usar `Math.abs` mais fácil de ler.

Comment: Concordo com você @PedroLorentz.

Answer (score -3):

Outra solução para o problema:

```
int N = -3
int R = ((N*2)+N)
```

O resultado de R é 3.

Comment: Além das óbvias  faltas de `;`, o resultado teórico e o que eu obtenha rodando na minha máquina é bem distinto do que você diz que obteve. Para mim, `R == -9`